# How to handle action wrapped inside other action in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, nested, action

Consider following emberjs-template :

```
<div>
    <div {{action 'outer_selected'}}>
        Outer Link
        <span {{action 'inner_selected'}}>
            Inner Link   
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

which basically wraps one action inside another. The problem is when I click on inner element, both actions get fired. How can I prevent the outer action from getting fired when clicked on inner element ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `bubbles=false` in your template to stop event propogation - http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_stopping-event-propagation

[Example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vujoqesi/1/edit)